# I have a problem with socket and pickles. Values ​do not save to in txt

Tags: python, sockets, ipc, pickle

The idea of ​​my Python code is to read values ​​from a network socket and with pickles save the values ​​in a txt file for later use in another application.

It does not necessarily have to be a txt file, but it is what I am trying to use.

The communication works very well, he creates the txt file, but unfortunately does not record anything.

Someone can help me.
Thanks.

Server Code:

```py
import socket
import pickle


HOST = ''              
PORT = 5000            
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
orig = (HOST, PORT)
tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(10)
filename = 'data.txt'


while True:
    con, cliente = tcp.accept()
    print('connector by', cliente)
    while True:
        msg = con.recv(4096)
        if not msg: break
        print(msg)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dumps(msg, f)

    print('Ending client connection', cliente)
    con.close()
```

Client Code:

```py
import socket


HOST = '10.0.0.120'
PORT = 5000
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)
tcp.connect(dest)

print('to exit press CTRL+C\n')
msg = input()
while msg != '\x18':
    msg = input()
    tcp.sendall(msg.encode('utf8'))


tcp.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. `pickle.dumps` produces a string and *does not* take a file argument. Indeed, you should be getting an exception from that code:

`TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedWriter)`

If you change your code to use `pickle.dump` instead, it works fine as that is the right method to dump to a file.  Here's an example that demonstrates it working (no sockets are necessary as this is about how `pickle` works, not about networking).

```
import pickle

foo = b'Some test string'
print("Pickling string '{}'".format(foo))

with open("/tmp/test.pickle", "wb") as tfile:
    pickle.dump(foo, tfile)

with open("/tmp/test.pickle", "rb") as tfile:
    bar = pickle.load(tfile)

print("Reloaded string '{}'".format(bar))
# Confirm they're identical
assert foo == bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
while True:
        msg = con.recv(4096)
        if not msg: break
        print(msg)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dumps(msg, f)
```

The code that opens the file is reached if and only if `bool(msg) is False`, because this is when the `while True` loop will terminate, as stated here: `if not msg: break`.

So `msg == ''`, and you end up writing the empty string